# How many explanatory variables do I have?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictor

I have bird abundances and hectares of land around ~4000 different routes. Hectares if land around each route are divided into 17 different land use types. I want to test whether the type of land around a route affects the bird abundance in that area.

I know the response variable is abundance, but are hectares and land use type considered two separate explanatory variables? Or would there be 17 explanatory variables (hectares of each land use type)?

I've included a sample of the data to this post.

[image]

Comment: Is the length of the route important, or might they all be approximately the same length?

Comment: I was given length of the routes as well. The main issue I'm having is that I was given a whole wack of data (probably more than I need), and I have to decipher what parts of the data I'll need to answer the question (does land use type affect bird abundance). It's for a semester long school project. I don't know if my independent variable should be all the 17 different land use types, or if maybe I should be incorporating things like route length and patch density (I don't even really know what patch density is).

Comment: Consider a first cut at the problem, rather than a final solution. If you can get a good approximation to refine, you are making progress. So I personally would go with [hectares of each type] as independant variables to start with, as this captures magnitude of type available on each route, and see what you get as a result.

Comment: That's what my intuition told me to do, but I was second guessing myself and needed a second opinion. Thanks @JamesPhillips!

Comment: Should I be concerned about interactions? I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of an interaction in this case. Does this description of a possible interaction, given my dataset, make sense: if having many hectares of one land us type, say wetlands, makes the probability of having many hectares of another land use type nearby, say open ocean, higher? If so, how can I determine which land use types should be checked for interactions? With 17 explanatory variables, this gives me many possible interactions.

Comment: You are wise in the ways of modeling. In this case I am recommending to start with a less complex model and analyze the preliminary results so that you have something to build on and refine.